# Does an I/O instruction cycles depend on the device's speed?

Tags: assembly, io, cpu-architecture, machine-instruction

For example,

```
in al, 8
```

If the device at port 8 is very slow, then does CPU have to wait for completion of the instruction in?

Thanks！

Comment: No.  A driver would only execute this instruction when the device signals that it has data available.

Comment: How to read the status register? Using another in instruction at another port? That's the same issue.

Comment: @HansPassant: A *good* driver would only do that. A bad one could easily block the kernel siting an waiting for a disk.

Comment: @xmllmx: No, it's not. A device that takes that long to respond to a status request is a broken device. It doesn't matter how fast a harddrive or CD drive is, the controller should be able to respond fast.

Comment: @Linuxios, Is it correct that a status register at certain port can be regarded as an address of memory? if considering I/O speed only?

Comment: @xmllmx: To be honest, I don't know. But the speed of the underlying storage medium or hardware type should be independent of the controller signaling the CPU that data is available.

Comment: @HansPassant: what would happen if the device responsible for handling a certain PIO address doesn't respond at all to a read request?

Comment: yes, that instruction path stalls until the I/O cycle is complete.  early x86 processors the whole thing was stalled, now only one execution unit and any dependencies, so you could craft code that would stall quite a bit of the processor if everyone is dependent on that in instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what part of the device is being "really slow". If it takes a lot of time to answer a PIO requests (like `in` and `out`), then yes, it will stall the execution unit (and everything that depends on it). The same would happen with "really slow" memory.

However, if the device takes a long time to complete its tasks (whatever they may be), but responds really quickly to PIO requests (e.g. indicating that it hasn't finished a task yet), then it doesn't really stall the CPU.

Properly designed hardware does the latter.